# Computing an Array from an Index Array and a Match Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have an index match that calculates as follows

```
=INDEX({0.0317988;0.039455;0.041596;0.04171;0.042447;0.042942},{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5})
```

When I compute this I get 0.0317988. How do I get this formula to return the 230 or so array of Index numbers based on the match array?

Comment: From what I see you only have an `INDEX()` with 6 items and you return multiple times items 1 to 5. To "visualize" everything, select cells `A1` to `A232` paste your formula and validate it with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

Comment: Or do you want to do something with that array like SUM or AVERAGE or something else?

Comment: The Match function is already computed above. When I compute the index formula above I get 6 values and they are all 0.0317988. I want to compute 230 values based on the match array.